# Django: encounter an OperationalError when migrate

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I encountered this error when deployed my code on a ubuntu server. I have tested the migration locally (macOS Mojave) and made no mistakes.

I tried to delete all migration files except the `__intit__.py`, but Django gave the same error.

The error traceback (home is the name of my app):

```
Applying home.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin/sites/site1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/admin/sites/site1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 381, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: REFERRING.S

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/admin/sites/site1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/admin/sites/site1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/admin/sites/site1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/admin/sites/site1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/admin/sites/site1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin/sites/site1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/admin/sites/site1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/admin/sites/site1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/admin/sites/site1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 247, in apply_migration
    migration_recorded = True
  File "/home/admin/sites/site1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 34, in __exit__
    self.connection.check_constraints()
  File "/home/admin/sites/site1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 341, in check_constraints
    column_name, referenced_column_name,
  File "/home/admin/sites/site1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/admin/sites/site1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/admin/sites/site1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/admin/sites/site1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/admin/sites/site1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/admin/sites/site1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 381, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: REFERRING.S
```

I don't have a column named REFERRING.S in my model explicitly, so I don't know what's happening here at all.

**Edit:**

Finally, I managed to make a minimal case to reproduce this error. It seems that this error is due to somehow like a database injection...

Here is the minimal case to reproduce this error.

```
from django.db import models


class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)


class Order(models.Model):
    orderNum = models.CharField(max_length=14, unique=True) 
    customer_idx = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)  

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'xxx(S)'
```

I have a model `Customer` and a model `Order` with the db_table named 'xxx(S)'. Maybe the "(S)" triggers some weird behavior. I'm a newbie to SQL and django. Could someone help me to explain this?

I'm using django 3.0.3 (and 2.2.5 also failed) and ubuntu 16.04. And this piece of code seems to work fine on MacOS.

**Edit 2:**

The migration script: 0001_initial.py

```
# Generated by Django 3.0.3 on 2020-02-21 16:49

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Customer',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Order',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('orderNum', models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)),
                ('customer_idx', models.ForeignKey(default=1, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='home.Customer')),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'xxx(S)',
            },
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: You may want to edit your question with a proper [mcve] - it's totally impossible to debug such an issue with only the traceback.

Comment: Also: "I tried to delete all migration files" => I don't know where you got this idea from, but that's about the worse thing you could do.

Comment: I tried to flush the database because it is empty and I also deleted the migration files and redid the makemigrations command, as I thought I could reset everything by doing this. @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: Upload the code of the 0001_initial.py migration file.

Comment: I have uploaded the minimal case and migration file. Thank you all!  @m0dknight

Answer (score 0):

You're referring the model `Order` to datable `xxx(S)`. Since the model `Order` is in relationship with `Customer` model, `Customer` model also should be there in same database `xxx(S)`.

Create meta class to Customer and refer to same database.

```
class Meta:
    db_table = 'xxx(S)'
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. The bracket in sql means column selection, so the table name "xxx(S)" were interpreted as select the column "S" of table "xxx". So just change the table name fixed the issue.